# pdf viewer for yosemite

Tags: macos, pdf

I have used several pdf viewers including Adobe's but they don't have full screen support with green button(pdf on another screen). Even if I do full screen then I can't view two pages in split mode on one screen. Viewing one page in full screen mode is very less information. Is there any visually and functionally better pdf viewer?

See the picture below. I read books in split 2-page mode. But, I can't zoom this further like other mac apps(Zooming with sliding to another full screen on right). If I zoom it further from view option then my 2 page view is lost. Which I don't want. Also, I don't want these irritation top bar options. I just want two plane pages in full screen mode.

[image]

Comment: You could always just set Preview to 'Zoom to Fit' Cmd/9

Comment: "Visually/functionally better" is highly subjective, can you describe in more details which specific functionality you are looking for, which viewers you have already tried and why they didn't match your requirements?

Comment: @patrix read it again. I have edited my question with more details.

Comment: Full screen would be like presentation mode, that is without Menu bar. Is that what you want ? I get it to show filling the Adobe window (100%) in non full screen mode (with tool menu or without it).

Comment: buscar go to view>page display> two page view. Now you can see two pages on one screen. Can you know open that in presentation mode? Thats what I want

Comment: Preview.app in fullscreen and showing two pages seems to work for me.

Comment: Yaa thats what i wanted preview worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Here is the result using Preview on 10.9.5 in full screen mode with 2 pages showing.

[image: preview 2 pages]

Answer (score 0):

The default Preview app that comes with OS X supports this...

Either before or after entering fullscreen mode you can press `Command 3` to enter into Two-up mode, and then use the `Command +` short cut to zoom in.